# extract images from PDF with PHP

Tags: php, image, pdf

The thing is that the client wants to upload a pdf with images as a way of batch processing multiple images at once.

I already looked around and out of the box PHP can't read PDF's.

What are my alternatives?

I already know the host has not installed `imageMagick` or any pdf library and the `exec` function is disabled. That's basicly leaving me with nothing to work with, I guess?

Does anyone know if there is an online service that can do this, with an api of sorts?

thanks in adv

Comment: I mentioned api, is it know in/on topic?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have a rather hard time getting this to work, it it's even possible with the current constraints you've mentioned. Perhaps you could convince the client to upload the images in a zip-file or something like that? Would make it a lot easier to work with at the very least!

Comment: It was never a subject of discussion, but I could mention it now. I will explore the suggestions Bishop gave to me about cutting the boundries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no PHP module to do it.  There is a command line tool, [pdfimages](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfimages1.html) (part of [xpdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpdf)).  For reference, here's how that works:

```
pdfimages -j source.pdf image
```

Which will extract all images from source.pdf as image-000.jpg, image-001.jpg, etc.  Note the output format is always Jpeg.

**Possible Options**

Being a command line tool, you need `exec` (or `system`, `passthru`, any of the command executing functions built into PHP).  As your environment doesn't have that, I see four options:

1. Beg that exec be turned on for you (your hosting provider can limit what you can exec to a single command)
2. Change the design -- how about a ZIP upload?
3. Roll your own, using the source code of `pdfimages` as a model
4. Let `pdfimages` do the heavy lifting, by running it on a remote host you do control

Regarding #3, rolling your own, I don't think rolling your own, to solve a very narrow definition of requirements, would be too difficult.  I seem to recall that the image boundaries in PDF are well defined: just read in the file to a boundary, cut to the end of the boundary, base64_decode, and write to a file -- repeat.  However, that may be too much...

If rolling your own is too complicated, then option #4 is kind of like what [Joel Spolsky describes for working with complicated Excel objects](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html) (see the numbered list under the bold heading "Let Office do the heavy work for you").

- Find a cheap hosting environment (eg Amazon EC2) that let's you `exec` and `curl`
- Install `pdfimages`
- Write a PHP script that takes a URL to a PDF, curl opens that PDF, writes it to disk, passes it to pdfimages, then returns the URL to the resulting images.

An example exchange could look like this:

```
GET http://www.cheaphost.com/pdfimages.php?extract=http://www.limitedhost.com/path/to/uploaded.pdf

Content-type: text/html


<html>
<body>
<ul>
<li>http://www.cheaphost.com/pdfimages.php?retrieve=ab9895v/image-000.jpg</li>
<li>http://www.cheaphost.com/pdfimages.php?retrieve=ab9895v/image-001.jpg</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

So your single pdfimages.php script (running on the host with the `exec` functionality) can both extract images, and give you access to the extracted images.  When extracting, it reads a PDF you tell it, runs pdfimages on it, and gives you back a list of URL to call to retrieve the extracted images.  When retrieving, it just gives you back a straight image.

You would need to deal with cleanup, perhaps the thing to do would be to delete the image after retrieval.  You would also need to handle security -- don't know what's in these images, but the content might need to be wrapped in SSL and other precautions taken.

Comment: it is not very clear to me how it should be used, is it not a PHP module?

Comment: It is not a PHP module: it's a command line program, so you would need exec. (I read over that part with my original answer: have revised since.)  Without exec, I think you will need to emulate what pdfimages does in PHP -- ie, roll your own.

Comment: you are joking right, roll your own? That is not simple I think.

Comment: If you don't have exec, and AFAIK there isn't a PHP module to do it, and you can't change the design... I see no other way than manual.  I edited my original answer to note that the image boundaries are pretty clear in a PDF, so finding them and cutting them should not be too difficult.

Comment: I will have to look into that, but creating your own api sounds interesting also, but I never done it. I have to think about that.In what format would you send it back?

Comment: Check out my edit. I propose a mechanism of sending back as an <ul> list of URL to retrieve the extracted images.  It could also be JSON if you wanted something easier to parse.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pdfimages and install it this way:

```
apt install poppler-utils
```

Then use it this way to get all the images as PNG files:

```
pdfimages -j mypdf.pdf image -png
```

Images will be placed in the same folder under image-000.png, image-001.png, etc.

There are many options available, including some to change the output format, more information [here](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-pdfimages/).

I hope this helps!