# PHP QR Code scan from PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, qr-code

I have a PDF file with a QR Code. Iuploaded the file on the server folder named "tmp" and now I need to scan and convert this QR via PHP.

I found this library:

```
include_once('lib/QrReader.php');
$qrcode = new QrReader('/var/tmp/qrsample.png');

$text = $qrcode->text(); //return decoded text from QR Code
print $text;
```

But this works only for png/jpeg files.
Is there any way to scan PDF ? Is there any way to convert PDF to png only the time that I need ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, transform your PDF into an image with [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), then use [your library](https://github.com/khanamiryan/php-qrcode-detector-decoder) to decode the QRcode from it:

```
include_once('lib/QrReader.php');
//the PDF file
$pdf = 'mypdf.pdf';
//retrieve the first page of the PDF as image
$image = new imagick($pdf.'[0]');
//pass it to the QRreader library
$qrcode = new QrReader($image, QrReader::SOURCE_TYPE_RESOURCE);

$text = $qrcode->text(); //return decoded text from QR Code
print $text;
//clear the resources used by Imagick
$image->clear();
```

Comment: tested, and this works for me instead of SOURCE_TYPE_BLOB  $qrcode = new QrReader($image, QrReader::SOURCE_TYPE_RESOURCE);

Answer (score 0):

You would want to convert the PDF to a supported image type, OR find a QR code reading library that supports PDFs. IMO the first option is easier. A quick search leads me to http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-convert-pdf-to-jpeg-in-php_498.html for a PDF -> img converter.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the QR code is embedded in the PDF as an image. You could use a command-line tool such as `pdfimages` to extract the image first, then run your QRReader library on the extracted image. You might need a bit of trial and error to establish which image is the QR code if there is more than one image in the PDF.

See [extract images from PDF with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20403127/5024519) for more detail.