# How to get multiple images from a multipage pdf in typoscript?

Tags: pdf, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Using an Images element I can add a PDF and have it render as a JPG. However it only does the first page. Is there any way to output each page as JPG files?

I am using the layout field to change how the images are rendered by typoscript. Can I split the pdf somehow?

eg.

```
# Image Layouts
temp.image < tt_content.image.20
tt_content.image.20 >
tt_content.image.20 = CASE
tt_content.image.20 {
  key.field = layout
  default < temp.image
  101 < temp.image
  101 {
    ??
  }
}
```

Comment: have you considered to use a PDF parser, extract the images and then add them on your fluid? Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402862/extract-images-from-pdf-with-php

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas I am not using fluid content elements. The default setup renders the first page as a jpg so I thought there might be a way to get the other pages as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Imgresource.html#frame) on TypoScript Reference you can use `frame` option to define the page:

```
10 = IMAGE
10.file = fileadmin/some.pdf
10.frame = 0

20 = < .10
20.frame = 1

etc.
```

But as I know there is no automatic mode to loop and detect if the frame exist in the pdf.

Comment: Do you know where this would work in the context of `tt_content.image.20` ?

Comment: I have actual non typo3 7.6 with `css_styled_content` so I can't answer this. As I know there is an Class wich render the Images. I don't know if this class respect the frame option. I think you have to write your own typoscript which render the wanted previews.